# Apache Cordova Visual Studio 2015 Community microphone communication App

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-2015, apache-cordova

I am trying to create my first Android App. I have my app look and how it will function, but I can't seem to find a plugin or anything on the internet about microphone communication. I can see that there is a `Microphone Record` in the `Media plugin` but that is not what I am looking for.  Does anyone know of something like this I can use?

If you know tell me if I need permission to add something like that on my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? http://plugreg.com/plugin/voicekick/cordova-plugin-microphone

You will have to add it as a custom plugin though.

Comment: Thanks that was the exact answer i was searching for. But can you just tell me if i would have copyright issues with this or not ?

Comment: @ConvXCODE you might want to check this LICENSE document to decide if it conflicts with your product. 

https://github.com/voicekick/cordova-plugin-microphone/blob/develop/LICENSE